# Prove that a given subspace of $C[-1,1]$ with $L^2$ norm is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, vector-spaces

Let $H= C[-1,1]$ with $L^2$ norm and consider $G=\{f \in H \mid f(1) = 0\}$. Show that $G$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

I've been trying to prove this for a while but i can't establish that given $\|f_n-f\|$ < $\epsilon$ (where the norm is the $L^2$ one)  we have uniform convergence for the sequence $(f_{n})$. If I could prove this the result would follow easily given that $G \subset \text{closure}(G)$ and if $(f_{n})$ converged uniformly we would have  $\displaystyle f(1)=\lim_{x \to 1} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 1} f_n=0$ and thus that $f \in G.$

Comment: This space is not closed in $H$ with respect to this norm.

Comment: And you don't have uniform convergence. For the closedness. The problem is, that you don't have a trace in $L^2$. Choose a sequence $f_n$ that is $1$ on $[-1,1-1/n]$ and then linear on $[1-1/n,1]$ so that the zero boundary condition is fulfilled. Hence your sequence of continuous functions converges in $L^2$ to the constant function $1$ which is not in $H$

Comment: You're right, thanks for the help, i guess my instructor made a typo.

Comment: Maybe it is a proposital typo.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this question but your sequence does not work (my instructor pointed out to me) as it converges to f(x)= 1 if x $\in$ [-1,1[ and 0 if x=1.

Comment: Do you have another counterexample or can you prove it isn't closed with inner product  $<f,g>\to \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)} dt?$

Comment: Nevermind, you guys were right

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is the kernel of the discontinuous linear map $L(f):=f(1)$. Indeed, $\ker f$ is is dense in $C[-1,1]$.

To see that, fix $f\in H$. For a fixed integer $n$, consider $f_n(x):=f(x)$ if $x\leqslant 1-n^{-1}$ and the graph of $f$ is a straight line joining $(1-n^{-1},f(1-n^{-1}))$ and $(1,0)$. Using the fact that $f$ is bounded, we can show that $f_n\to f$ in $H$, and $f_n\in G$ for all $n$.

Comment: I think your first $H$ should be $G$, like your last $V$.

Comment: @julien Right, fixed now. Thank you.